# Rounding in a case expression

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select, rounding

I have a case state that I would like to apply round to the final results. The column is importstring.  21.16800000000000.  I would like to have it rounded to 2.  I have attempted to use Round(21.1680000000,2).  Can this be done?

```
 SELECT   ITMMASTER.ITMREF_0,
          YPRIMAT.ITMREF_0,
          BASPRI_0,
          ITMMASTER.TSICOD_6,
           ITMMASTER.TCLCOD_0,
  (BASPRI_0*2.205+CASE
                 WHEN ITMMASTER.TCLCOD_0 = '32221'  --Multipying 2.205 times 
  1.25 (packaging per pound)
                       THEN '2.75625'
                 WHEN ITMMASTER.TCLCOD_0 = '32224' --Multipying 2.205 times 
  0.75 (packaging per pound)
                       THEN '1.65375'
                 WHEN ITMMASTER.TCLCOD_0 = '13221' --
                       THEN '2.75625'
                 WHEN ITMMASTER.TCLCOD_0 = '13241'
                       THEN '1.65375'
                 WHEN ITMMASTER.TCLCOD_0 = '36221'
                       THEN '6.7473'
                 WHEN ITMMASTER.TCLCOD_0 ='36224'
                       THEN '5.6448'
                 WHEN ITMMASTER.TCLCOD_0 = '41211'
                       THEN '1'
                 END) AS Importstring

  FROM LIVE.YPRIMAT
  INNER JOIN LIVE.ITMMASTER  ON YPRIMAT.ITMREF_0 = ITMMASTER.ITMREF_0
```

Comment: Why are you multiplying strings, e.g. `'1'`? Wouldn't it make more sense to use numbers, e.g. `1`? And what is a "case state"? TSQL does have a [`case`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) _expression_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can surround the expression with `round()`:

```
round(baspri_0_2 * 2.205 + case .. end, 2) as ImportString
```

Or, possibly better, you can `cast()` to a decimal that has two decimal places:

```
cast(baspri_0_2 * 2.205 + case .. end as decimal(30, 2)) as ImportString
```